# Why are Workflow Exceptions are not caught when thrown from Cancel?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, native-activity

I am using Microsoft Windows Workflow Foundation in my Windows based application.

I have subscribed to `OnUnhandledException` on workflow for any unexpected exception.

The `OnHandledException` callback is received for all exceptions inside workflow but **cancel case**.

Consider the `WorkflowApplication.BeginCancel(..., ..)` is called which eventually invokes the cancel on activities, now if exception is thrown from within `Activity`(Derived from Native activity) upon cancel call then **OnUnhandledException callback is not received**.

I know that I can still get a `CancelCallBack` for `BeginCancel` and I can do the same stuff as `OnUnhandledException`, however I would want to refrain myself from doing so. Also code is more understandable if there is standard protocol - (if there is an exception, no matter from where, the `UnhandledException` callback should receive a call).

If such is the protocol provided by Microsoft for Workflow, it would be really great if you can share documentation link which mention this unique case of cancel or suggest if I need to do anything extra to get this callback.

The following is the sample code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter values for following operations");
        Console.WriteLine("c: Cancel");
        Console.WriteLine("p: Progress. This is a multiple resume operation you can press p as many times you want untill workflow is completed or aborted!!");
        Console.WriteLine("f: Finish");
        Console.WriteLine("0 i.e Zero: Exit");
        Console.WriteLine("=============================================");

        var wf = CreateWorkflow();
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        while (a.ToString() != "0")
        {

            switch (a.ToString().ToLower())
            {
                case "c":
                    {

                        //wf.Cancel();
                        wf.BeginCancel(AsyncCallBackMethod, null);
                        break;
                    }
                case "f":
                    {
                        wf.ResumeBookmark("Finish", null);
                        Console.WriteLine("Workflow completed press 0 to exit.");
                        break;
                    }
                case "p":
                    {
                        wf.ResumeBookmark("Progress", "Hello World");
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid input");
                        break;
                    }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("=============================================");
            Console.WriteLine("==============Enter next operation===========");
            a = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter to exit");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void AsyncCallBackMethod(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancel callback");
    }

    static WorkflowApplication CreateWorkflow()
    {
        WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new SampleActivity()) { SynchronizationContext = new SynchronousSynchronizationContext() };

        // Handle the desired lifecycle events.
        wfApp.Completed = delegate (WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CompletionState == ActivityInstanceState.Faulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Workflow {0} Terminated.", e.InstanceId);
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}\n{1}",
                    e.TerminationException.GetType().FullName,
                    e.TerminationException.Message);
            }
            else if (e.CompletionState == ActivityInstanceState.Canceled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Workflow {0} Canceled.", e.InstanceId);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Workflow {0} Completed.", e.InstanceId);
            }

            Console.Read();
        };

        wfApp.Aborted = delegate (WorkflowApplicationAbortedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Workflow {0} Aborted.", e.InstanceId);
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}\n{1}",
                e.Reason.GetType().FullName,
                e.Reason.Message);
        };

        wfApp.Idle = delegate (WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Workflow {0} Idle.", e.InstanceId);
        };

        wfApp.PersistableIdle = delegate (WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
        {
            return PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
        };

        wfApp.Unloaded = delegate (WorkflowApplicationEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Workflow {0} Unloaded.", e.InstanceId);
        };

        wfApp.OnUnhandledException = delegate (WorkflowApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnUnhandledException in Workflow {0}\n{1}",
            e.InstanceId, e.UnhandledException.Message);

            Console.WriteLine("ExceptionSource: {0} - {1}",
                e.ExceptionSource.DisplayName, e.ExceptionSourceInstanceId);

            return UnhandledExceptionAction.Cancel;
        };

        wfApp.Run();

        return wfApp;
    }
}

public class SampleActivity : NativeActivity
{
    protected override sealed bool CanInduceIdle
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        Console.Write("Inside Activite Execute");
        CreateBookmarks(context);
    }

    protected override void Cancel(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        throw new Exception("Some Exception");
    }

    private void CreateBookmarks(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.CreateBookmark("Progress", OnProgressRecieved, BookmarkOptions.MultipleResume);
        context.CreateBookmark("Finish", OnCalculationFinished);
    }

    protected virtual void OnProgressRecieved(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object sender)
    {
        var name = sender as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"On Activity Progress called. Welcome {name}");
    }

    protected virtual void OnCalculationFinished(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object sender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"On Activity finished called.");

        context.RemoveAllBookmarks();
    }
}

public class SynchronousSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        d(state);
    }
}
```